# Weak references and anonymous classes

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm in a situation where I have a static list caching some references. As this is a static list, I want to use WeakReference so I don't keep my objects in memory uselessly.

The issue - I think - I have is that one of the references is an anonymous class. My fear is that if I store the anonymous class as a WeakReference, it might be collected really quickly, and if I store the anonymous class as a strong reference, it will hold a reference to the class that constructed the anonymous class.

I don't know if my explanation is clear, so here is a piece of code:

```
public interface Callback {
    void call();
}

public class A {
    public void doIt() {
        B.register(this, new Callback() {
            public void call() {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
}

public class B {
    private static final List<Item> ITEMS = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void register(Object key, Callback callback) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.key = new WeakReference<>(key);

        // ??
        item.callback = new WeakReference<>(callback);

        ITEMS.add(item);
    }

    private static class Item {
        private WeakReference<Object> key;
        private WeakReference<Callback> callback;
    }
}
```

Basically, if in Item 'callback' is a weak reference, it might be garbage collected before I even get the chance to use it.
And if in Item 'callback' is a standard reference, the instances of 'A' will never be garbage collected.

So my first question: is my understanding right?
Second question: is there a way to make it work or do I have to change the design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Callback` is a functional interface you can use a lambda instead. Lambdas only capture the variables they reference. So if the lambda is a pure function, a static method reference or only references local variables it will not capture `this`. If you reference `this`, an instance method or instance field then it will capture.

The same can be achieved by replacing the anonymous class with an static inner class or a separate class.

It is unclear why you're using two separate weak references per `Item`. You could simply keep the item itself in a weak reference and have strong refs to `key` and `callback`, they would be effectively weak when item itself is only weakly reachable.

In general you should reason about paths from GC roots. If an object is only reachable from a GC root with a path of references where even a single one of the references is weak then the whole subgraph is only weakly reachable and thus eligible for collection.

> Basically, to have my item released only when 'A' need to be released.

Then a `WeakHashMap<A, Callback>` is what you want. Just ensure that `Callback` does not reference `A`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the lambdas were not keeping the instance, interesting. And also you're right, I haven't thought of having the whole item as a weak reference! Good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it, if I store my Items with weak references, won't I have the same issue as when I stored my Callback as a weak reference? I mean to have the item collected before I even get a chance to use it. I know that the principle with the weak references (you don't know when they will be collected) but I'd like to keep my items as much as I can. Basically, to have my item released only when 'A' need to be released. Am I overthinking and I'll still be fine because weak refs are not collected that often? (Would a SoftReference make any difference?)

Comment: I am sure it's correct (and very pertinent) that "if the lambda is a pure function, a static method reference or only references local variables it will not capture `this`" but I haven't been able to find that in official documentation.  Could someon point to that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4